# "Explanation power" of a parameter

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, model, nonparametric

Suppose there are two practically similar statistical models with similar "breath": $L(\theta)$ and $M(a,b)$, where $\theta, a, b$ are parameters. When fitting with data, if we assume that $b$ is fixed, then the fit of $M$ is usually worse than $L$.

In plain words, this might be due to, intuitively, $a$ only contributing to about half of the "explanation power" of $M$, while $\theta$ contributes to the full explanation power. It is not surprising to see that $L$ fits better than $M$.

What is the appropriate name for "explanation power"? How to properly describe this phenomenon? I only took one statistics class so I am not sure which word I should use.

Comment: Perhaps one of those: Explanatory Power? Explanatory Ability? Incremental amount of variance?

Comment: Unfortunately, the premise of your question is flawed.  Since you have not specified the breadth of the models $L$ and $M$, there is no reason to believe that $M(\cdot, b)$ would be less general than $L(\cdot)$.  There is also no basis for the claim that the first parameter in the model would contribute half the "explanatory power", however defined.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I am happy that you commented! It is very helpful. I believe what you said is very rigorous. I tried to do some research on "breadth". Would you mind to share the rigorous definition of the "breadth" of a statistical model?

Comment: I will not give a rigorous answer, but usually the "breadth" of a model is commonly measured by the dimensions of the parameter space.